# How can I check if a microphone is plugged into the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, microphone

I'm using AVAudioRecorder in the AVFoundation framework.
I'm wondering how I can check for a microphone device being plugged in (on the iPod Touch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Device Support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html) section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide is your friend

> In iPhone OS 3.0 and later, use the
>   AVAudioSession class to determine if
>   audio input is available. This class
>   accounts for many different sources of
>   audio input on iPhone OS–based
>   devices, including built-in
>   microphones, headset jacks, and
>   connected accessories. For more
>   information, see AVAudioSession Class
>   Reference.

Answer (score 5):

`BOOL inputAvailable = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] inputIsAvailable];`