# How can I tell whether a microphone is available on the device (iPhone, iTouch or iPad)?

Tags: iphone, audio, ios

If the device has a microphone, I would create audio device as "play and record". If the microphone is not available, only "play" audio device can work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a microphone is plugged into the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282871/how-can-i-check-if-a-microphone-is-plugged-into-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered already?

[How can I check if a microphone is plugged into the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282871/how-can-i-check-if-a-microphone-is-plugged-into-the-iphone)

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the answer. 

 NSError *error;
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
 
 if (![audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error])
 {
  return NO;
 }
 
 // mix audio with others, such as iPod etc.
 UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
 AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck, 
        sizeof(doSetProperty), 
        &doSetProperty);
 
 if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&error])
 {
  return NO;
 }
 
 return audioSession.inputIsAvailable;

Comment: Sorry, the code is a little bit mess. You can copy it to Xcode and indent it.