# How to detect whether mic available in device(iPhone/iPad)- Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, hardware, microphone

In my `iOS` application, I want to show an `Alert`, if `Mic is not available in the device`.

How can I check this ?

I have tried this-

```
 -(void)checkMic
 {
  UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio;
   OSStatus status = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);  //..always seems to return OK..
   status = AudioSessionSetActive (true);
   if(status)
   {
      //mic is not available
    }
  }
```

But this code is showing an error with message - deprecated.

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282871/how-can-i-check-if-a-microphone-is-plugged-into-the-iphone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AudioSessionSetProperty` and `AudioSessionGetProperty` are deprecated as of iOS 7.  Use `AVAudioSession` instead.

You can use its `availableInputs` property to get a list of what's available and iterate through them to find one that looks like a microphone, like this:

```
NSArray *availableInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
BOOL micPresent = false;
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *port in availableInputs)
{
    if ([port.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic] ||
        [port.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic])
    {
        micPresent = true;
    }
}

if (micPresent)
{
    // Do something cool
}
else
{
    // No mic present - show alert
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want any input at all, and don't care if it's a mic or a line-in, you can just do:

```
if ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] inputAvailable];
{
    // Do something cool
}
else
{
    // No input present - show alert
}
```

Comment: FYI - `inputIsAvailable` was deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use `inputAvailable` instead.

Comment: @rmaddy: You are correct.  I've edited the answer to keep it up to date.  Thanks.

Comment: how to detect if the microphone is owned by a call (if the phone is during a call)

Comment: @Qusai Azzam - did you get any solution?

Comment: well, I did, where do you want me to explain it? @sachingupta

Comment: please email at sachin.gupta@bridgera.com

Comment: @QusaiAzzam availableInputs gets inputs but doesn't check if they are in use. I found `inputDataSources` to do what I needed, which is check if it's in use (it will be empty array if in use by background call for instance)

Comment: well, I found another way to handle that.